# Does a screensaver need permission by game Company?

Tags: screensaver, rights

Lets say I like Super Mario, Take some Screenshots while playing. Its legal to Post Screenshots. What if i Program a screensaver with my Screenshots to earn money. The screensaver will be Sold for Windows. Would that be legal or would i break Nintendos rights?

Regards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming, but is instead asking for legal advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about legal issues, not programming or coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not legal to post screenshots of copyrighted and not free-licensed game. So its the same case for a screensaver.

Posting or selling one or the other is illegal. Also, there might be copyright infringement involved.